# Firebase: How to check if user already exists

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have setup authentication with microsoft login using firebase, this is the code inside my signIn function:

```dart
User user = await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow(
          "microsoft.com", ["email openid"], {'tenant': 'common'});
```

Now i want to store some data to firestore if this is the first time that the user has logged in, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try these as per newly added APIs on Firebase Auth..

[AdditionalUserInfo](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/AdditionalUserInfo-class.html) -> `isNewUser → bool`

[UserMetadata](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/UserMetadata-class.html) -> `creationTime → DateTime?`

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to check the authenticated users from firebase you have to register the users in the database when you first authenticate it and check from that database if the user exists or not.